# Loop isn't breaking when a specific string is inputted

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

When the user inputs `pBreak`, it should break the while loop. However, this isn't working and I'm confused on why. Could somebody please help me?

```
package main;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TextFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                String line = input.next();
                if (line == "pBreak") {
                    break;
                }
                out.write(line);
                out.newLine();
            }
                out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `equals` instead of `==`. Consider, null-safe `equals`

```
 if ("pBreak".equals(line)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will also work:

```
if (line.equals("pBreak")) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` operator will compare the references of the two operands.
As `line` variable is a different string object's reference ,it will not match to string literal constant reference `pBreak` while comparing.

```
if (line .equals("pBreak")) {
  break;
}
```

So equals() method has to be used to compare the String.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (line == "pBreak") {
```

to

```
if (line.equals("pBreak")) {
```

`==` compares object *references*, `.equals(String)` compares String *values*.